# TSS Shadow applied to text, not background of button

Tags: button, titanium, shadow, appcelerator-titanium, tss

I'm trying to apply a shadow to a button, but instead of appearing around the background of the button, it is appearing behind the text. How do I get the shadow to appear around the bg.

My TSS

```
".shadow":{
    shadowColor: '#F2FFFF00',
    shadowOffset: {x:"3",y:"3"}
}
```

My button in the XML

```
<Button id="welcomeBtn1" onClick="welcomeGotoFAQS" class="welcomeButton columnMargin verticalMarginBtm shadow"  />
```

[image: Button Grab]

Thanks in advance of your help.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the doc, shadow color and Offset are apply to the title. try to put the button inside a view and apply the shadow on this view.